# Guidelines for learning Cloud Computing

Tags: azure, cloud

I have been primarily a web application developer with .NET as the primary technology used. I have been thinking about learning Cloud Computing as a subject and working with some implementation details with Microsoft Azure. But I have not been able to properly comprehend on where to start about the entire concept about Cloud Computing and how to go about staring with MS Azure. Can anyone point me to some good, easy to understand resources for Cloud Computing in general and a good book on Microsoft Azure Technology(preferably one which explains the technology in the perspective of code).

Comment: This question doesn't fit the Q&A format of StackOverflow, as it's not a specific programming question. That said, the [Windows Azure webpage](http://www.windowsazure.com) is the best place to start your journey and has a complete overview of Windows Azure, language-specific developer pages, pricing, and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any book on Windows Azure gets out of date pretty quickly as the platform is moving very fast. With that said here are 3 I would recommend;

1. The Windows Azure Handbook, Volume 1: Planning & Strategy: Windows Azure for Business and Technical Decision Makers (David Pallmann - http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=David+Pallmann&x=0&y=0) Gives a good look at the business side of cloud computing and Azure;
2. Programming Windows Azure: Programming the Microsoft Cloud (Sriram Krishnan - [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows-Azure-Microsoft-Cloud/dp/0596801971/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1332171031&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596801971)) A good introduction from the programming perspective
3. Azure In Action (Chris Hay, Brian Prince - [http://www.amazon.com/Azure-Action-Chris-Hay/dp/193518248X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1332171126&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193518248X)) Another great book focused around the code.

Also, for more up to date coverage and the opportunity to get some directed hands-on experience be sure to check out the Windows Azure Training Kit (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8396) and focus especially on the Hands-On-Labs.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Another book I'd recommend is Neil Mackenzie's ["Microsoft Windows Azure Development Cookbook"](http://www.packtpub.com/microsoft-windows-azure-development-cookbook/book).

There are also the Windows Azure Boot Camps and Windows Azure Kick Start events.